# Why doesn't this return the position for the largest item in the array list

Tags: java

```
public static int findLargestMark(ArrayList<Result> array)
{
    int last = 0;
    int largestPOS = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= array.size(); i++)
    {
        for (Result s : array)
        {
            int num = s.getMark();

            if (num > last)
            {
                last = num;
                largestPOS = i++;

            }
        }
    }
```

Does anyone have any idea why this isn't returning the position of the largest value?
I'm sorry but I'm a bit of a newbie to Java.

Comment: Why do you have **two** loops?

Comment: and no return statement

Comment: You're not returning anything...

Comment: Assuming there is a return statement, what if two Result objects have the same (largest) value for the mark attribute? Do you want to return the last position in that case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. `largestPOS = i++;`

   This is incrementing `i` which means it skips the next number.  If that next number is the biggest, you'll miss it.
2. Your code won't compile.  You need a return statement.
3. Your outer loop skips the first element because it starts at 1 instead of 0.  Arrays and lists are 0 based.
4. You only need one loop to accomplish this.  I'd remove the inner loop since you're trying to return the index and a `for`each loop doesn't give you the index.
5. If your array is empty, it will set `largestPOS` to 0.  That is not correct.  Other algorithms in this situation would return -1 to mean "index not found".  See `String.indexOf` for example.

Comment: And a whole bunch of other reasons like the code won't even compile

Comment: Well, the loop won't miss the next value, since the code has two loops.

Comment: he just wanted to be double sure he found it :P

Answer (score 4):

If you want to find the largest mark, no need to reinvent the wheel. Use [`Collections.max`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#max%28java.util.Collection,%20java.util.Comparator%29) and provide a custom [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) :

```
Result r = Collections.max(array, new Comparator<Result>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Result o1, Result o2) {
                return Integer.compare(o1.getMark(), o2.getMark());
            }
        });
```

Then if you really want to find the position of this object in the list you can use [`indexOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#indexOf%28java.lang.Object%29) :

```
array.indexOf(r);
```

Note that will return the index of the **first** occurrence of the specified element in the list.

If you want to get the index of the **last** occurrence, you can use :

```
array.lastIndexOf(r);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several reasons to this program's failure:

- You need to check that your `array` has at least one item
- You need to start the `last` at the initial mark, not at zero
- You need to loop from one, inclusive, to `array.size()`, exclusive
- You do not need a nested loop
- You need to add a `return` statement

Here is how you can fix your code:

```
public static int findLargestMark(ArrayList<Result> array) {
    if (array.size() == 0) return -1; // 
    int last = array.get(0).getMark();
    int largestPOS = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < array.size(); i++) {
        int num = array.get(i).getMark();
        if (num > last) {
            last = num;
            largestPOS = i;
        }
    }
    return largestPOS;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you're iterating through the same array using two nested loops. Keep it simple. Iterate only once through the entire array and find the maximum value and its index.

Answer (score 0):

Your code even not compile, java is `0` index based. you should have received a `ArrayIndexOfBoundException`. However, i would just use [**`Collections.max(array, Comparator`**)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#max%28java.util.Collection,%20java.util.Comparator%29):

```
    Result x = Collections.max(array, new Comparator<Result>(){

                @Override
                public int compare(Result o1, Result o2) {
                    return Integer.compare(o1.getMark(), o2.getMark());
                }
            });
```

And then the index by [**`array.indexOf(x)`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#indexOf%28java.lang.Object%29) function, where `array` is an instance of type `ArrayList<Result>`

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
 public static int findLargestMark(ArrayList<Result> array)
{
    int last = array.get(0).getMark();
    int largestPOS = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i <= array.size(); i++)
    {
            Result s = array.get(i);
            int num = s.getMark();
            if (num > last)
            {
                last = num;
                largestPOS = i;

            }

     }
     return largestPOS;
}
```